# Vídeo que completa toda a tela

Tags: html, css

quero fazer com que meu vídeo completo toda a janela do navegador,
tentei colocar com width e height 100%, mas não funciona.
Apena o Width se ajusta à tela mas o height não.
Código html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Teste</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
        <source src="meee.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No meu fica "fullscreen" limpa o cache da página

Comment: já consegui, mas vlw